# Javascript error related with the sdk.js

Tags: rally

I'm trying to use a custom page inside Rally that links to my external application using an iframe. During runtime I'm getting one javascript error related with the sdk.js file from Rally.

I'm doing something wrong?

Javascript error:

[image: Javascript error from sdk.js]

Code used for my custom page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0p4/sdk.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Rally.onReady(function() {
        Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',

            launch: function() {    

        var user = this.getContext().getUser(); 
            var projectId = Rally.environment.getContext().getProject().ObjectID;
        document.write('<div id="Timesheet"><iframe src="https://myserver/Entry.aspx?RallyUserName=' + user.UserName + '&RallyProject='+ projectId +'" height=90%  width=100% style="border-top-width: 0px;border-right-width: 0px;border-bottom-width: 0px;border-left-width: 0px;"></iframe></div>');                 

            },


        });            

        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name: 'Timesheets'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Regards,
Paulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're getting strange errors deep inside the sdk it is often helpful to include sdk-debug.js rather than sdk.js.  You will get a better stack trace that may help you track down what is going on.

In this case your document.write code is blowing away dom elements that the app expects to be there.  Use Ext to create your dom elements and you should be all set:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    items: [
        { xtype: 'container', itemId: 'Timesheet' }
    ],

    launch: function() {
        this.down('#Timesheet').add({
           xtype: 'component',
           autoEl: {
               tag: 'iframe',
               src: '',
               //...
           }
        });
    }
```

Or from any container or component within the app you can always call getEl() and work directly with the dom elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the Custom URL App for this need:

[image: Add App...]

[image: Custom URL]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my external URL is dynamic. It must include the user email and the selected project. Using the custom URL I'm only able to do it static.